# How to add application widget in home screen of launcher application?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, launcher, homescreen

I have created a simple launcher application and also an application widget. This app widget works perfect in home screen of default launcher (Press and hold on home screen --> Widgets ---> MyExampleWidget).

I want to implement the same behavior in my launcher application home screen too.

I am following the sample home application http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

Would you please help me?